# Is there a way to format tooltip values in Altair boxplot

Tags: python, altair

Is is possible to format the values within a tooltip for a boxplot? From this [Vega documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/boxplot.html#tooltip-encoding-channels), it appears so, but I can't quite figure out how to do it with Altair for python

```py
from vega_datasets import data

import altair as alt

source = data.population.url

alt.Chart(source).mark_boxplot().encode(
    alt.X("age:O"),
    alt.Y("people:Q"),
    tooltip=[
        alt.Tooltip("people:Q", format=",.2f"),
    ],
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you need to provide an aggregation for composite marks like `mark_boxplot`. This works:

```
from vega_datasets import data
import altair as alt

source = data.population.url

alt.Chart(source).mark_boxplot().encode(
    alt.X("age:O"),
    alt.Y("people:Q"),
    tooltip=alt.Tooltip("mean(people):Q", format=",.2f"),)
```

[image]

**Update:** As it is currently [impossible to add multiple aggregated tooltips to a boxplot](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/7918), I combined my answer with [How to change Altair boxplot infobox to display mean rather than median?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59194197/how-to-change-altair-boxplot-infobox-to-display-mean-rather-than-median) to put a transparent box with a custom tooltip on top of the boxplot. I still kept the boxplot underneath in order to have the outliers and whiskers plotted as a Tukey boxplot instead of min-max. I also added a point for the mean, since this is what I wanted to see in the tooltip:

```py
alt.Chart(source).mark_boxplot(median={'color': '#353535'}).encode(
    alt.X("age:O"),
    alt.Y("people:Q"),
    tooltip=[
        alt.Tooltip("people:Q", format=",.2f"),
    ],
) + alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(color='#353535', size=15).encode(
    x='age:O',
    y='mean(people):Q'
) + alt.Chart(source).transform_aggregate(
    min="min(people)",
    max="max(people)",
    mean="mean(people)",
    median="median(people)",
    q1="q1(people)",
    q3="q3(people)",
    count="count()",
    groupby=['age']
).mark_bar(opacity=0).encode(
    x='age:O',
    y='q1:Q',
    y2='q3:Q',
    tooltip=alt.Tooltip(['min:Q', 'q1:Q', 'mean:Q', 'median:Q', 'q3:Q', 'max:Q', 'count:Q'], format='.1f')
)
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, works for me too, thanks! Would there be a way to add additional tooltips ... this doesn't seem to work for me (sorry for ugly formatting in comment, didn't quite know how to do that correctly)       ```alt.Chart(source).mark_boxplot().encode(
    alt.X("age:O"),
    alt.Y("people:Q"),
    tooltip=[
        alt.Tooltip("mean(people):Q", format=",.2f"),
        alt.Tooltip("min(people):Q", format=",.2f"),
    ],
)```

Comment: @BrentGunderson I am not sure why multiple tooltips do not work with boxplors, but it is probably related to them being aggregate plots. I would ask it as a new question tagged with `vega-lite` and see if there are any suggestions.

Comment: @BrentGunderson I needed this myself today so I looked more into it and I can confirm that this is indeed a bug in VL https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/7918. A workaround is to build the chart from scratch as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59194197/how-to-change-altair-boxplot-infobox-to-display-mean-rather-than-median

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to add multiple columns to the tooltip. You can pass in multiple columns in square brackets as a list.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

stocks = data.stocks()

alt.Chart(stocks).mark_point().transform_window(
    previous_price = 'lag(price)'
).transform_calculate(
    pct_change = '(datum.price - datum.previous_price) / datum.previous_price'
).encode(
    x='date',
    y='price',
    color='symbol',
    tooltip=[ 'price', 'symbol', alt.Tooltip('pct_change:Q', format='.1%')]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a realistic tooltip example with multiple tooltips! From Altair's documentation, I had hard time to figure out to specify for multiple tooltip components, as it just focuses on a single component. Your example shows the additional dimension of the specifications.