# Python: Altair boxplots - how to add information to the standard tooltips?

Tags: python, altair

I found this Stackoverflow question which shows how to replace the Altair boxplot tooltips.

[Is there a way to format tooltip values in Altair boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66614926/is-there-a-way-to-format-tooltip-values-in-altair-boxplot)

How can I use the standard tooltip and add additional information to it? (I need to add mean and StDev).

Is it possible without replacing the existing tooltip? Otherwise, how can I add the a description for the tooltip?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can consider modifying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59194197/how-to-change-altair-boxplot-infobox-to-display-mean-rather-than-median)

Comment: That is great, thank you - exactly what I have been looking for.